# How do I loop a command in Unity for a specified amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an attack script for the player in unity. The attack would work by creating a transform in front of the player and when the player pressed the attack button, a one second timer would be started where any enemies that entered the transform would be killed. After the timer ended the enemies wouldn't be killed anymore when entering the transform. I tried to do that by looping the essential command for killing the enemies for one second using the `InvokeRepeating` command. However I never used it before so of course it didn't work. I have to mention that I used `StartCoroutine` to make the command repeat for one second. I apologize for my lack of knowledge as I am new to Unity and programming. Anyway here is the code:

```
public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform AttackArea;
    bool IsAttacking = false;
    public Animator animator;
    public LayerMask EnemyLayers;
    public float AttackRange = 0.5f;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {

            animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
            StartCoroutine(AttackLoop());
            Attack();
            InvokeRepeating("Attack", 0, 0);
        }
    }


    void Attack()
    {

            Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackArea.position, AttackRange, EnemyLayers);
            foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
            {
                enemy.GetComponent<Enemy_1>().Death();
            }

    }
    


    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (AttackArea == null)
            return;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(AttackArea.position, AttackRange);

    }
    IEnumerator AttackLoop()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        {
            CancelInvoke("Attack");
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Your `Attack` method is not connected to the coroutines in any way. It does not get affected by them starting or stopping at all (and you only call it once anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to create a single coroutine that tracks time using `Time.deltaTime` and loops until the appropriate time has elapsed:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        StartAttack();
    }
}

void StartAttack()
{
    float attackDuration = 1.0f; // attack for 1 second
    animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
    StartCoroutine(AttackLoop(attackDuration));
}

void Attack()
{
    Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackArea.position, AttackRange, EnemyLayers);
    foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
        enemy.GetComponent<Enemy_1>().Death();
    }
}

IEnumerator AttackLoop(float attackDuration)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0f;
    while (elapsedTime < attackDuration) 
    {
        Attack();
        yield return null;
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```